# What arguments is the class asking for when I call upon the class and the function in it

Tags: swift, arguments

I want to use the unique flight ID that is display prior to access my dictionary and cancel the flight that is matching with the flight ID the user has inputted. But what argument am i supposed to put so that the user input gets send back to the flight class and generate changes? (I just added some default values below, since i don't understand the error)
.cancelflight() is the actual method I want to call upon. The user input section is from my main.swift file and it is an if statement from a function .

```
print("Please insert the flight ID of the flight you want to cancel: ")
    let operCancelID = Int(readLine()!)!
    let operCancel = Flight(flightID: operCancelID, departCity: "", arriveCity: "", scheduledDate: 0, flightDistance: 0.0)


    operCancel.cancelFlight()
```

Below is some of my flight class code:

```
class Flight {

var flightID : Int
var departCity : String
var arriveCity : String
var scheduledDate : Int
var flightDistance : Double

init(flightID: Int, departCity: String, arriveCity : String, scheduledDate : Int, flightDistance: Double){
    self.flightID = flightID
    self.departCity = departCity
    self.arriveCity = arriveCity
    self.scheduledDate = scheduledDate
    self.flightDistance = flightDistance
}

//Declare dictionary
var flightDict : [Int: Any] = [:]

func toString(){ // Use String Custom Convertible property thing?
    print(flightDict)
}

func addFlight(){
    flightDict = [flightID : [departCity, arriveCity, scheduledDate, flightDistance]]
    print(flightDict)
    }


func editFlight(){
    flightDict.updateValue((departCity, arriveCity, scheduledDate, flightDistance), forKey: flightID)
    print(flightDict)

    if let (flightID) = flightDict.updateValue((departCity, arriveCity, scheduledDate, flightDistance), forKey: flightID){
        print("Your flight has been changed. \(flightID)")
        }else{
            print("No flight has been changed. \(flightDict)")
        }
}

func cancelFlight(){
    print(flightDict)
    flightDict.removeValue(forKey: flightID)
    if let (flightID) = flightDict.removeValue(forKey: flightID){
        print("Your flight has been canceled: \(flightID)")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your question without more context. If it is difficult to explain the problem, I suggest adding more code like that of your `Flight` class and show with some examples of what the input will be and what you want your expected output to look like.

Comment: So sorry about that, I mainly want user to input their flightID and so the ID (acting as the key in the dictionary) can locate the flight and cancel it. And the output should show that particular flight has been canceled. Same goes for all the other functions, like addflight and edit flight. Sorry again.

Comment: It's fine, we just ask clarifying questions to understand your problem better. Before solving your problem, I feel there is some issues to be resolved with the design. Thinking out loud, In your `Flight` model, when you instantiate a new flight using the init method, you create one flight object. This one flight object should now also access the flights dictionary with all the flights ? This does not seem right. I suggest to either keep the flightDictionary in the main or make another class like `FlightManager` that tracks all the flights created.

Comment: Or make flightDict a static variable